# If/else with Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, conditional-statements

Apologies for the noob question but I struggle with python conditionals.

Have the following dataframe:

```
id  bonus
1   1.5
2   1.12
3   1.09
4   0.9
5   0.74
6   0.83
```

I have upper and lower limit variables:

```
upper_limit = 1.2
lower limit = 0.8
```

Trying to write a conditional that:
1) Checks if the bonus is above or below the threshold
2) Creates a new column that ensures the value doesn't go above or below the thresholds. If the bonus value is within range, it doesn't change.

Should look like:

```
id  bonus   bonus_capped
1   1.5     1.2
2   1.12    1.12
3   1.09    1.09
4   0.9     0.9
5   0.74    0.8
6   0.83    0.83
```

My code is:

```
conditions = [df["bonus"] > upper_limit, df["bonus"] < lower_limit]
choices = [upper_limit, lower_limit]

df["bonus_capped"] = np.select(conditions, choices)

print(df)
```

but the output I'm getting is only addressing one condition and returning zeros for the rest. What am I missing?

```
id  bonus   bonus_capped
1   1.5     0
2   1.12    0
3   1.09    0
4   0.9     0
5   0.74    0.8
6   0.83    0
```

Comment: your code works for me - additionaly it returns 0 because that's teh default - try `np.select(conditions, choices,default=df['bonus'])`

Answer (score 3):

This will be easy using `numpy.clip`:

```
import numpy as np

df['bonus_capped'] = np.clip(df['bonus'], 0.8, 1.2)
```

where 0.8 and 1.2 are your lower and upper limits respectively.

Answer (score 2):

In `pandas`

```
upper_limit = 1.2
lower_limit = 0.8
df.bonus.clip(lower_limit,upper_limit)
0    1.20
1    1.12
2    1.09
3    0.90
4    0.80
5    0.83
Name: bonus, dtype: float64
#df.bonus=df.bonus.clip(lower_limit,upper_limit)
```

Answer (score 1):

By going with the method you were trying:

```
In [1100]: col         = 'bonus' 
      ...: conditions  = [ df['bonus'] < 0.8 , df['bonus'] > 1.2] 
      ...: choices     = [0.8, 1.2]                                                                                                                                                                         

In [1102]: df['bonus_capped'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=df['bonus'])                                                                                                                         

In [1103]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1103]: 
   id  bonus  bonus_capped
0   1   1.50          1.20
1   2   1.12          1.12
2   3   1.09          1.09
3   4   0.9           0.9
4   5   0.74          0.80
5   6   0.83          0.83
```